# How to empty out the whole tableview on a button click in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios4

In my iPhone app, I am using a single tableview to display different sets of data based on the button clicked.

Now as I am using the same tableView I need to blank out the tableView contents everytime a new button is selected.

And this is quite normal requirement rite? As such it is inefficient to take 7 tables to show 7 different data sets.

**Problem:**

I have seen that table clears out but when we display some other data in the table then the previous data appears in background as in Screenshot AFTER. 
I have tried setting the array as nil and reloading the tableView but then it doesnt seem to work.

What can be a fix for this issue?

I have checked the code and it seems proper to me.

You can refer to the Screen shot to get a better idea of what actually is happening.

**BEFORE ( i.e. the first time Event is clicked)**

[image]

**AFTER (i.e. once the Event category button is clicked after some other category button)**

You can clearly see a different image in background where as it should be same as image in above screenshot. This is not a button, I am adding a UIImageView to tableViewCell.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSArray is not mutable, that is, you cannot modify it.

Instead of using NSArray use NSMutableArray and use

[mutArr removeAllObjects];

and then reload the tableView. It worked for me.

Comment: I tried the same but doesnt work for me. It desnot empty out the table as the [mutArr count] is 0 when we reloadData and hence it returns 0 in numberOfRowsinSection method for tableView. As a result of which it doesnot go into cellForRowAtIndexPath method.  What should be done in that case?

Comment: Checkout that you have properly synthesize tableView. I have also faced this problem once, on debugging i have found that there is two diff instance is created for same tableView. Please check it

Comment: I have added the screenshots about the problem I am facing. Please Check that. What can be done in that case? Also I have synthesized my tableview so there should not be any issue with that.

Comment: I think u are using different array for each button action. If so, post your code i will check it

Comment: @kingfBliss: Thanks for your input. No, I am using the same array for each button and I am just setting the array value to nil and then putting the new data into the same array on each button click.

Comment: As such I am using Array. I also tried using Mutable Array but with no success.

Comment: You cant change the value of NSArray like this. What are you doing to remove values from mutable array? setting it to nil?

Comment: It worked for me. I tried again and it did refresh the tableview Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
- (IBAction)yourAction {
tableView.delegate = nil;
tableView.dataSource = nil;
[tableView reloadData];
```

}

it will empty your table view... ur need is not clear

Comment: I have added the screenshots about the problem I am facing. Please Check that. What can be done in that case?

Answer (score 0):

In button action method, call the tableView reload and assign null to object from which you are initializing the cells previously,

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Read the question above. I have already mentioned the null out the array and reloading the tableView doesn't seem to work. Anyways thanks for the input.

Comment: what i understand is that you want to see the empty cells in tableview and currently you are having no cells in tableView on button click ??

Comment: No I want to clear out the existing data and fill in new data in the tableView on the button click. I have added the screenshots about the problem I am facing. Please Check that. What can be done in that case?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will work if your array is nil. Try initializing it as a empty array with:

```
myArr = [NSArray array];
```

And then reload the tableView data. Otherwise I think we need to see your code

**EDIT**

It is still a bit unclear(still no code in your question), but I think your problem is really related to your cell construction. Are you adding UIImageView on every cellForRowAtIndexPath message?

I guess you have something similar to:

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

      static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellName";

      myCell *cell = (myCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
      if (cell == nil) {
          //CONSTRUCT CELL. 
          //THIS IS THE ONLY PLACE WHERE YOU SHOULD ADD SUBVIEWS TO YOUR CELL
      }

    //Are you adding subviews here? -you shouldn't
    //configure data in cell
    return cell;
```

Comment: I have added the screenshots about the problem I am facing. Please Check that. What can be done in that case?

Comment: without having seen the code it will be guesswork, but it looks very much like you are adding a new uiimageview on top of a existing uiimageview in the cell.

Comment: Thanks for the input. In ContentView of tableViewCell, I am adding an imageView as a subview. Also as you said I might be adding an ImageView over existing ImageView. So how can I remove the previous ImageView?

Comment: You should not remove the imageview...You should simple only add it once. See my code example above.

Answer (score 0):

You can return zero for numberOfRowsInSection, and add BOOL variable for isEmpty.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
if(isEmpty){
       return 0;
    }else{
       // your current logic
    }
}

//action when button clicked
-(IBAction)myAction{
    isEmpty = TRUE;
    [self reloadData];
}
```

Comment: I have added the screenshots about the problem I am facing. Please Check that. What can be done in that case?